# How to add a property to project.json after nuget package installation?

Tags: nuget, .net-core

I have a NuGet package that contains a .NET Core library let's call it *calculator*, whenever a client project installs my package a configuration property needs to be added in an existing configuration section in the client's project `project.json`.

Example:
This is the client's initial `project.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "confSection": {
        "intialConfig": true
    },
    ...
}
```

and this is what it needs to look like after installing the library

```
    {
            ...
            "confSection": {
                "intialConfig": true,
                "addedConfig": true
            },
            "dependencies": {
                "calculator": "0.1.0"
             }
            ...
}
```

**How to achieve this?**
**Is there a post install script facility in NuGet that will allow to write scripts that perform the preceding?**

Answer (score 3):

NuGet will find and execute two magic scripts inside a nuget package that the Package Manager Console in VS will execute when it opens (tools/init.ps1) and installs (tools/install.ps1), but these are not supported anywhere outside of Visual Studio and are not guaranteed to execute when packages are restored using project.json.